# HTML buttons get widened and stretched rightward after adding 1px columns for vertical bars

Tags: html

Newbie.
I have 5 buttons, Welcome, About Us, Services, Experience and Contact Us.  They are sized and spaced correctly until I add 1px columns in between them to add vertical gray bars to separate the buttons.  As I add the vertical separator lines, the image and button areas start to get stretched starting from the left side.  With all lines added, the distortion is pronounced from the left, but the far right button (Contact Us) still looks ok.

This code has the vertical bar columns commented out:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                <img alt="" src="images/whitepixel.gif" height="14" width="770" border="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="17">
                <img alt="" src="images/whitepixel.gif" height="65" width="17" border="0">
            </td>
            <td width="183">
                <a href="McD_index.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_logo.gif" height="65" width="183" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <td width="17">
                <img alt="" src="images/whitepixel.gif" height="65" width="17" border="0">
            </td>
            <!--
            <td width="1">
                <img alt="" src="images/vertBar.png" height="65" width="1" border="0"
            </td>
            -->
            <td width="111">
                <a href="McD_welcome.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_WelcomeON.png" height="65" width="110" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <!--
            <td width="1">
                <img alt="" src="images/vertBar.png" height="65" width="1" border="0"
            </td>
            -->
            <td width="111">
                <a href="McD_aboutus.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_AboutUsOFF.png" height="65" width="111" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <!--
            <td width="1">
                <img alt="" src="images/vertBar.png" height="65" width="1" border="0"
            </td>
            -->
            <td width="111">
                <a href="McD_services.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_ServicesOFF.png" height="65" width="111" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <!--
            <td width="1">
                <img alt="" src="images/vertBar.png" height="65" width="1" border="0"
            </td>
            -->
            <td width="111">
                <a href="McD_experience.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_ExperienceOFF.png" height="65" width="111" border="0"></a>
            </td>
            <!--
            <td width="1">
                <img alt="" src="images/vertBar.png" height="65" width="1" border="0"
            </td>
            -->
            <td width="111">
                <a href="McD_contactus.html">
                    <img alt="" src="images/menu_ContactUsOFF.png" height="65" width="110" border="0"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                <img alt="" src="images/whitepixel.gif" height="15" width="770" border="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                <img alt="" src="images/greenpixel.gif" height="15" width="770" border="0">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Everything I try has not worked!

I just want the buttons to appear normal width and evenly spaced with vertical line separators.  My vertBar.png file is just a 1 px gray vertical bar

Thanks!

Comment: This is giving me a massive headache. Move away from using a table for layouts (though sometimes there are instances where you'd need them, but this isn't one of them) and start using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you on your way:

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="#">option 1</a><a href="#">option 2</a><a href="#">option 3</a><a href="#">option 4</a>
</div>

<div id="content" class="container">
<p>Hello, world</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menu {width:90%;margin:14px auto;background:oldlace}
#menu > a {display:inline-block;line-height:65px;padding:0 10px;border-right:1px solid red;}
#menu > a:hover {background:skyblue}
.container {width:90%;margin:0 auto;}
```

check: http://jsfiddle.net/68Hhc/

Comment: I was afraid of CSS because of my poor HTML ability, so I needed your push into CSS.

Comment: I was afraid of CSS because of my poor HTML ability, so I guess I needed your push into CSS.  I'm using w3schools.com and some Android apps for references, but are there better references guides for HTML and CSS, in terms of complete syntax, etc?  For example, I'm looking for your CSS example code and cannot find #menu.  Also, is it possible that your CSS code might be conflicting with an internal style sheet which also contains A and A:hover codes?

Comment: @MikeMac https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web comes to mind, it's as good a place to start as elsewhere. #name is simply to link to the id of an element, in this case the div with the 'menu' id. Furthermore, CSS reads top down, so it is possible to overwrite certain rules you set prior or setting rules that don't work well with other set rules.